# Ensure User.username is unique even when User is deleted

Tags: django, unique

I would like to know how, using Django, to ensure the uniqueness of a field value, even if objects are deleted.

For example, I create a `CustomerUser` with username = "carlos" , delete this user, then if I create another `CustomerUser` with username= "carlos" I will get an error.

```
models.py

class CustomUser(models.Model):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=100 , unique=True)
```

```
shell

user_one = CustomUser.objects.create(username="carlos")
user_one.delete()
user_two = CustomUser.objects.create(username="carlos") ---> This should not be possible.
```

Should I save in another model all the usernames created or there is a Django function that assures the uniqueness of the username will be always True even after object deletion?

Comment: You can soft delete the user thus by specifying with a `BooleanField` that the user is removed, but is still in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for example if I create a script to delete from the database all the users that haven't been online for 5 days, your solution will still work ?

Comment: you can make use of a dajngo softkill package that does that. In that case the boolean is altered. You should of course not work with a database script, but let the package alter how such object is "removed"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=100 , unique=True)
      is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then just update the `is_delete` to True and filter user according that.

```sh
user_one = CustomUser.objects.create(username="carlos")
user_one.is_delete = True
user_one.save()
```

During filter you do something like this:

```sh
user_one = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_delete=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a package like [**`django-soft-delete`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-soft-delete/). This package will not remove the record, but add an extra `BooleanField` named `is_deleted` that is set to `True` in case the object is removed. But the record itself still exists.

The package will thus override the `.delete()` method of the model object, and also use record managers that will for example count the number of records with `is_deleted` set to `False`, at the same time the database will still enforce that no two records with the same name will exist.